# View List with 2 filtering

Tags: list, list-view, filter

I want to add 2 filtering a list.

1. List item not to be shown after the Closing date
2. List item not be shown till the Publish date reaches.

I've added a Closing and Publish Date on my list.
But not sure if I can run 2 different nature of filters at the same time on a list?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can.

Just go to `modify view` page, and add the filters like this:

1. `closing date` is greater than or equal to `[Today]`
2. `publish date` is less than or equal to `[Today]`

Comment: that doesnt works. Any option to get both the filters working?

Comment: any article or exact procedure, as in my case adding the 2 filters gives error. I guess need a add a rule with none value prior to adding rule for  closing date. Same in case of Publish date.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using? How many items do you have in your list? I have never ever faced an issue of this kind.

Comment: I`ve tested after adding the publish date filter.
The items disappear the next day, so its visible the day when the publish date matches. I`m after wherein the items remains visible post publish date filter execution.